# powermail 2.0.16 on Typo3 6.1.10

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, powermail

I tried to change the Fields in the List from Powermail. I can see the changes in the backend - but there are no changes in the frontend. Even after deleting cache etc.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Typo3 6.1.10 is very old and not maintained anymore. I recommend updating to at least 6.2.x or higher.

But powermail 2.0.16 on Typo3 6.1.10 should work according to Extension Repository. Maybe deleting cache in Install Tool helps or deinstalling and reinstalling the extension. If you still try to solve the problem maybe it helps to know that when the powermail 2.0.16 extension was released there was used PHP 5.3 or 5.4 or 5.5 as stable versions.